# Displaying inner objects in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am trying to display my user_roles in my application.

Here is my bean

```
private Set<ClientRole> clientRoles = new HashSet<>();
```

Here is the object in my bean i am trying to display in Thymeleaf.

```
<tr th:each="clients : ${clientsList}">
                                    <td th:text="${clients.client_id}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.emailaddress}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.firstname}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.lastname}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.phone}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.companyname}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.companyurl}">...</td>
                                    <td th:text="${clients.clientRoles?.role}">...</td>
                                </tr>
```

Client Role entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
public class ClientRole {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long userRoleId;

public ClientRole(Client client, Role role) {
    this.client = client;
    this.role = role;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private Client client;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;

public ClientRole() {}

public long getUserRoleId() {
    return userRoleId;
}

public void setUserRoleId(long userRoleId) {
    this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
}

public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

Here is the role Entity. Bean trying to access the roles though
thymeleaf. as i am using thymeleaf extras spring security 4. i would
like admin users to be able to modify roles. i would like to be able
to display as well as modify.The other fields display properly but the
clientRolse is giving me a long string .
com.zenopoint.domain.Client.clientRoles

```
@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
private int roleId;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
 FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<ClientRole> clientRoles = new HashSet<>();

public Role() {

}

public int getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<ClientRole> getClientRoles() {
    return clientRoles;
}

public void setClientRoles(Set<ClientRole> clientRoles) {
    this.clientRoles = clientRoles;
}

public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}
```

}

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
 public String accounts(Model model) {
    List<Client> clientsList = userservice.findUserList();
    model.addAttribute("clientsList", clientsList);
    return "app/accounts";
}
```

Here is my userService

```
 public List<Client> findUserList() {
    return clientDao.findAll();
}


public interface ClientDao extends CrudRepository<Client , Long> {
    Client findByPhone(String phone);
    Client findByEmailaddress(String emailaddress);
    Client findByUsername(String username);
    List<Client> findAll();
}



@Entity
public class  Client  implements  UserDetails{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long client_id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    @Email
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String emailaddress;  
    @NotEmpty
    private String companyname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String companyurl;
    @NotEmpty
    private String street;
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;
    @NotEmpty
    private String region;
    private String zip;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doj = new Date();
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstname;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;
    private String nationality;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String phone;
    @NotEmpty
    private String position;    
    private boolean enabled = true;
    private String registrationnumber;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transactions> transactions;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tokenization> tokenization;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<ClientRole> clientRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public Client() {}

    public Long getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }


    public void setClient_id(Long client_id) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getEmailaddress() {
        return emailaddress;
    }


    public void setEmailaddress(String emailaddress) {
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }


    public String getCompanyname() {
        return companyname;
    }


    public void setCompanyname(String companyname) {
        this.companyname = companyname;
    }


    public String getCompanyurl() {
        return companyurl;
    }


    public void setCompanyurl(String companyurl) {
        this.companyurl = companyurl;
    }


    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }


    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }


    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }


    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }


    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }


    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }


    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }


    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }


    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }


    public Date getDoj() {
        return doj;
    }

    public void setDoj(Date doj) {
        this.doj = doj;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }


    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }


    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }


    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }


    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }


    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }


    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }


    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }


    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }


    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }


    public String getRegistrationnumber() {
        return registrationnumber;
    }


    public void setRegistrationnumber(String registrationnumber) {
        this.registrationnumber = registrationnumber;
    }


    public List<Transactions> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }


    public void setTransactions(List<Transactions> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }


    public List<Tokenization> getTokenization() {
        return tokenization;
    }


    public void setTokenization(List<Tokenization> tokenization) {
        this.tokenization = tokenization;
    }


    public Set<ClientRole> getClientRoles() {
        return clientRoles;
    }


    public void setClientRoles(Set<ClientRole> clientRoles) {
        this.clientRoles = clientRoles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client [client_id=" + client_id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password
                + ", emailaddress=" + emailaddress + ", companyname=" + companyname + ", companyurl=" + companyurl
                + ", street=" + street + ", city=" + city + ", region=" + region + ", zip=" + zip + ", dob=" + dob
                + ", doj=" + doj + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", nationality="
                + nationality + ", phone=" + phone + ", position=" + position + ", enabled=" + enabled
                + ", registrationnumber=" + registrationnumber + ", transactions=" + transactions + ", tokenization="
                + tokenization + ", clientRoles=" + clientRoles + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        clientRoles.forEach(ur -> authorities.add(new Authority(ur.getRole().getName())));
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: All objects are displaying correctly  but for the clientRole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nested Loop:

```
<td data-th-text="${clients.clientRoles}">...</td>
<td>
    <tr th:each="a: ${clients.clientRoles}">
        <td data-th-text="${a.role.name}">...</td>
    </tr>
</td>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your Thymeleaf code looks correct. Do you add objects to your Set of ClientRole entities? And do you add it to your Model in your Spring Controller with `model.addAttribute("clientsList", clientRoles);` ?

If not, please provide us the code of your Controller class and of the  ClientRole entity.

Comment: so to display the Role name and Role id you have to use the following in your thymeleaf `${clients.role.name}` and `${clients.role.roleId}`

Comment: please provide the Controller code where your use model.addAttribute(...,..). Currently i dont know if you add a List of Role objects or ClientRole objects to your view

Comment: EL1008E: Property or field 'role' cannot be found on object of type 'com.zenopoint.domain.Client' - maybe not public?

Comment: i thought you pass a List of ClientRole objects to your view? please show me your controller

Comment: I do get the list of Roles for each client but it is displayed as such . 
 [com.zenopoint.entities.security.ClientRole@7bcddd01] .  how do i convert this?  clients with 2 or more roles get 2 or 3 of this separated by a comma

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are getting an object `Role` with this line of code
`<td th:text="${clients.clientRoles?.role}">...</td>`.

All you have to do is go one layer deeper to get the `Role` **name**.

Update your code like so

```
<td th:text="${clients.clientRoles?.role.name}">...</td>
```

---

**Update 1**

Since you `clientRoles` is mapped as `@OneToMany` entity in your `Client` entity, your `client` object will be having a list of `clientRoles`.

This line of code `<td th:text="${clients.clientRoles?.role}">...</td>` is not correct because `clients.clientRoles` is actually a list of roles.

You need to iterate the `clientRoles` to get all the `roles` a client is having.

Comment: EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?

Comment: Please update your post with `Client` entity as well. There seem to be some discrepancy in the mappings i believe.

Comment: The problem could also be because `clientRoles` will be a list of `roles`.

Comment: Client enitity added  @Abdullah Khan